# How to stop onclick event?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I'd like to stop `onclick` if I pressed it twice, but somehow it doesn't work...

what am I doing wrong?

```
var timer
timer = document.querySelector("#home").onclick = function () {
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("Expenses"); }, 1000);
}
console.log(timer);

document.querySelector("#home").setAttribute("ondblclick", "buildActionButton()");


function buildActionButton() {
  timer.stopPropagation();
  alert("ActionButton");
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Stop the timeout or remove the eventListener?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the event using ['addEventListener'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of just changing its 'onclick' property. You can then use ['removeEventLister'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) to remove the 'onclick' event.

Comment: I don’t want to remove the event, i would like to skip it

Comment: @Bayo What do you mean by 'skip it'?

Comment: I would like to keep the ‘onclick event’ and not to remove my ‘onclick event’